# Converting List[str] into List[list]

Tags: python, arraylist

I need to format the first list into the same format as the second one.

```
print(incorrent_format_list)
['AsKh', '2sAc', '7hQs', ...]


print(correct_format_list)
[['As', 'Kh'], ['2s', 'Ac'], ['7h', 'Qs'], ...]
```

I tried:

```
for h in incorrect_format_list:
         split_lines = h.split(", ")
# but the print output is this:

['AsKh']  
['2sKh']
['7hQs']


#rather than what i need: 

[['As', 'Kh'], ['2s', 'Ac'], ['7h', 'Qs'], ...]
```

Comment: Does your incorrect list only contain items with the equal length of 4 character, and should they always be split exactly into two parts of 2 characters? Is it possible for something like 'AsKh2' to exist in the incorrect list? Or should the lists always be split on capital letters? Or something else? Please be explicit

Answer (score 2):

You can just slice the strings as follows:

```
my_list = ['AsKh', '2sAc', '7hQs']

corrected_list = [[e[:2], e[2:]] for e in my_list]

print(corrected_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[['As', 'Kh'], ['2s', 'Ac'], ['7h', 'Qs']]
```

Answer (score 1):

After learning the basic for loop method as suggested in the other answers, you could also do this in 1 line by mapping a function to each value in your initial list

```py
a = ['AsKh', '2sAc', '7hQs']
list(map(lambda i: [i[:2], i[2:]], a))
```

The idea is to split each string in the middle by slicing it. 2 is being used here as each item is of a fixed length.

Comment: This produces the correct output but is unnecessarily complex and is 20% slower than a simple list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Split by capital letters if that is the case in whole list

Considering `incorrect_list=['AsKh', '2sAc', '7hQs']`

```
import re
correct_format_list=[]
for i in incorrect_list:
    correct_format_list.append(re.split('(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])', i))
print (correct_format_list)
```

Output:

```
[['As', 'Kh'], ['2s', 'Ac'], ['7h', 'Qs']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `more_itertools` library and slice the string. Then append those splitted list of string into your output list (fs):

```
from more_itertools import sliced

ss = ['AsKh', '2sAc', '7hQs']
fs = []
for h in ss:
    fs.append(list(sliced(h, 2)))

print(fs)
```

Output:

> [['As', 'Kh'], ['2s', 'Ac'], ['7h', 'Qs']]

Comment: sorry my bad @Pingu., forgot to remove it while testing

Comment: This is extremely slow when compared to a simple list comprehension